# Promise.then is not a function error only on server

Tags: javascript, angular, promise, es6-promise

I am running the below code on local which is working fine but on server I have this error:

> Promise.then is not a function

```
let promise = null;
  if (this.fileUrl) {
    promise = this.pdfJS.getDocument(this.fileUrl);
  }
  else if (this.base64FileData) {
    const pdfData = atob(this.base64FileData);
    promise = this.pdfJS.getDocument({ data: pdfData });
  }
  console.log('pretty');
  console.log(promise);
  
  promise.then(function (docObj) {
    console.log('promistest');
    console.log(docObj);
    this._loadingEnd();
    this.renderPages(docObj);
  }, this._onDocumentLoadError.bind(this)
);
```

Comment: the simplest debugging step is to see what `console.log(promise);` outputs

Comment: you could add `else promise = Promise.reject("invalid state")` then let the `this._onDocumentLoadError` handle the error

Comment: console.log(promise); retruns the data

Comment: so, that means it's NOT a promise and therefore doesn't have a `.then` method - try `promise.promise.then` since `pdfJS.getDocument` returns an object that has a `promise` property - as per [documentation](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/examples/) (though, that may NOT be the correct documentation for whatever you're using, I just realised) - what is `this.pdfJS` and what does `this.pdfJS.getDocument` return?

Comment: @JaromandaX this is working but, now i am unable to render the document

Comment: i used    promise.promise.then(function (docObj) {

Comment: OK, cool, so now the question is completely unrelated? I'd suggest trying to see what's wrong, then ask a new question since this question is now solved

Comment: I've added an answer since this may confuse other people in the future

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The object returned by `.getDocument` is not a promise, but it has a property called `promise`

therefore

```
let promise;
if (this.fileUrl) {
    promise = this.pdfJS.getDocument(this.fileUrl).promise;
} else if (this.base64FileData) {
    const pdfData = atob(this.base64FileData);
    promise = this.pdfJS.getDocument({ data: pdfData }).promise;
} else {
    promise = Promise.reject('invalid state');
    // this will be handled by `this._onDocumentLoadError.bind(this)`
}
console.log('pretty');
console.log(promise);
promise.then(function (docObj) {
    console.log('promistest');
    console.log(docObj);
    this._loadingEnd();
    this.renderPages(docObj);
}, this._onDocumentLoadError.bind(this));
```